# How to authenticate users in WebServices with Key using different checks

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm working with a Web Api which is using Active Directory to authenticate users. I'm using this Api in PHP to login user that are in my WEB API key (The key is in "Web.Config" file). I'm new to c# web api and there is something wrong which I'm unable to resolve. I need to insert some checks for user. First one is If user is not in the key "Return Not Allowed". If user is in the key but the username or password is invalid "Return Invalid UserName or Password" and if the user input is true then log the user into the system.

```
public string IsAuthenticated(string user, string pass, string domain)
        {
            DirectoryEntry objDirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, user, pass);
            try
            {
                string UserName = user.ToString();
                string Password = pass.ToString();
                string Domain = "Netsolpk";
                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(objDirEntry);
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
                if (result == null)
                    return "You're not in the Domain";
                string AdAuthentication = IsAuthenticated(UserName, Password, Domain);
                string[] name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"].Split(',');
                string authorized = "false";
                foreach (var author in name)
                {
                    if (AdAuthentication == "true" && author.ToLower() == user.ToLower())
                    {
                        return "true"; //login
                    }
                    else if (author.ToLower() == user.ToLower())
                    {
                        return "Invalid Password";
                        authorized = "true";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (AdAuthentication == "false")
                {
                     return "Not Allowed";
                }
                return "false";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return "false";
            }
        }
```

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="name" value="DavidR,JohnH"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: What is your problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Where is exactly your problem?
2. Have a look at JWT authentication Tokens. It's a nice way to return cancellation tokens, if the user is unauthorized or return a token to log in. You can test the API easy with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Here is a little example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginModel GetLoginData)
{
  /// Get SAM and Passowrd
  var service = new JSON();
  var LoginUser = service.GetData(GetLoginData);
  _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, $"User {LoginUser.SAM} tried to Login.");

  /// Checks if user is allowed to login
  var db = new DB();
  bool IsAllowed = db.GetUserBySAM(LoginUser);

  if (IsAllowed == true)
  {
    /// Checks if Password is correct in LDAP
    var ldap = new LDAP();
    bool PasswordCorrect = ldap.IsUserPasswordCorrect(LoginUser);

    if (PasswordCorrect == true)
    {
      /// Gets Userdata from AD
      LoginUser = ldap.GetUserData(LoginUser);
      var auth = new Authentication();

      /// Generates a Token which expire in 5 minutes
      var JwtToken = auth.CreateToken(LoginUser);

      _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, $"User {LoginUser.SAM} successfully logged in.");
      return Ok(new
      {
        token = JwtToken,
        allowed = "Authorized",
        username = LoginUser.SAM,
        firstname = LoginUser.FirstName,
        lastname = LoginUser.LastName
      });
    }
    else return Unauthorized();
  }
  _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, $"User {LoginUser.SAM} is not allowed to login.");
  return Unauthorized();
}
```